# How to use Doxygen and Doxygen::Filter::Perl to generate documentation for Perl sub routines?

Tags: perl, doxygen

I am trying to figure out how to use [`Doxygen::Filter::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Doxygen::Filter::Perl) to generate documentation for Perl files. I am starting with a very simple file just to see if I can get it to work (`test_doxygen.pl`):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#** @file test_doxygen.pl
#  @brief  Testing Doxygen using Doxygen::Filter::Perl
#
# Description of the purpose of this file
#
#  @author Håkon Hægland (hakon.hagland@gmail.com)
#
#  @bug No known bugs.
#
#*

#** @class main
# The main class
#*

use strict;
use warnings;

my $b = add_one(1);

#** @function public add_one ($par1)
# @brief A brief description of the function
#
# A detailed description of the function
# @params $par1   required  A number
# @retval value   Input value plus one1
#*
sub add_one {
    my ($par1) = @_;

    return $par1 + 1;
}
```

I then installed Doxygen::Filter::Perl and used the `Doxyfile` configuration file provided by the package maintainer at metacpan.org ([the link is here](https://metacpan.org/source/JORDAN/Doxygen-Filter-Perl-1.62/Doxyfile))
and put it in the same directory as the script above. I changed one line in the `Doxyfile`: the value of the `INPUT` tag was changed from `lib` to the empty string, in order to only search the current directory for source files..

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, so I installed Doxygen with `sudo apt-get install doxygen`, (I also needed to install `graphviz`: `sudo apt-get install graphviz`) then I finally run

```
$ doxygen
```

from the terminal window. The generated HTML file `doc/html/index.html` contains documentation about the file and the author, but it does not contain any documentation for the `add_one` sub routine.

What am I missing here?

**Update**

Here is how the class view looks like in Chromium browser:

[image]

As seen, there is no reference/link to the `add_one` sub routine.

And here is the file view:

[image]

Comment: You are missing the idea that Perl Progammers use [pod](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlpod)?

Comment: @mob After reading this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722619/is-there-really-no-better-way-to-document-perl-code-than-pod I decided to try Doxygen :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the problem was with handling the "my" variable declaration.  It set the value to be private: and doxygen never went back.  I have added a line to Perl.pm to fix this and it should work for you now.  Since you are working with pl files not pm files, I have also made changes to the Doxyfile, so you will want to get the new one from the distribution.  I have published 1.71 to Github and CPAN and have tested it with your exact example.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. It is working now! It looks great, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I just posted a new version of Doxygen::Filter::Perl to Github and CPAN, version 1.70.  This should fix the problems you were seeing.

Comment: Thanks @jordan2175. But it still does not work. I ran `cpanm Doxygen::Filter::Perl` to update to version 1.70. Then rerun `doxygen` command, but I still get the same result. No `add_one` subroutine in either class view or file view in the browser..

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at this and it seems to work with Doxygen (1.7.5.1), however, the newer version of Doxygen (1.8.9.1) does not seem to work well.

Comment: Thanks @jordan2175. I am using version 1.8.6.